# how do i set the connection string for my web application in azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I created a web application using the ASP.Net 5 web application template and published to an Azure web application.

In the Settings section of my web app I was able to create a Data Connection.
How do I tell my web application to use this data connection.

[Update]
the name of the connection string in my appsettings.json is DefaultConnection

Comment: have you look at this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/ ?

Comment: and I think this is might help you https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

Comment: The Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager NuGet package gives you a uniform API. Maybe this fits in your solution.

Comment: I have found connection strings under Settings->Application Settings

Answer (score 3):

Please try this...

1. Go to Azure web app > configure > connection strings.
2. Add a connection string with the name DefaultConnection.
3. Use Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString") to access it.

Example using timesheet_db instead of DefaultConnection
This is an example from my own timesheet application. My connection string was named timesheet_db. Just replace all instances of that string with DefaultConnection to adapt the example to your use case.

Azure web app configuration
[image]

Azure web app service control manager
The online service control manager at https://myWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env will show the connection strings.

[image]

Startup.cs
Setup configuration settings in Startup so that the environmental variables overwrite the config.json

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public Startup()
{
 Configuration = new Configuration()
    .AddJsonFile("config.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();    <----- will cascade over config.json
}
```

Configure the database in Startup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
  services
    .AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<ProjectContext>(options =>
    {
        var connString =
            Configuration.Get("Data:timesheet_db:ConnectionString");
        options.UseSqlServer(connString);
    });
  }
```

Of course, the example uses a connection string named timesheet_db. For you, replace all instances of it with your own connection string named DefaultConnection and everything will work.

Comment: I cant find a menu option called Configure inside my web app

Comment: I am using App Services then I click on the web app I have set up. There is a Settings menu but no configuration menu option.

Answer (score 1):

App Services, then select the web app, then Settings, then Application Settings.
Scroll down to connection strings.
Make sure the connection is named DefaultConnection